# Get ranking on mysql produce wrong ranks

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i'm trying to get ranking based on rating percentage so mysql query like

```
select c.id , sum((r.value * 20))/ count(r1.pagetypeid)  as score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank from (SELECT @curRank := 0) cr, rating as r 
inner join rateelement as r1 on r.elementid = r1.id
inner join ratesubscription as r2 on r.subscriptionid = r2.id
inner join consultant as c on r2.consultantid = c.id
where r1.displayorder not in (6) and r2.agencyid = 38
group by  c.id order by score desc
```

but it returns wrong raking indexes

[image]

what's wrong with the query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Ranking with variables often has issues with `group by` -- and even `order by` in the most recent versions of MySQL.  So, use a subquery:

```
select x.*, (@curRank := @curRank + 1) AS rank
from (select c.id, sum((r.value * 20))/ count(r1.pagetypeid) as score 
      from rating r inner join
           rateelement r1
           on r.elementid = r1.id inner join
           ratesubscription r2
           on r.subscriptionid = r2.id inner join
           consultant c
           on r2.consultantid = c.id
      where r1.displayorder not in (6) and r2.agencyid = 38
      group by c.id
      order by score desc
     ) x cross join
     (SELECT @curRank := 0) cr;
```

Comment: hi @Gordon thanks for the reply but this getting error `1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from rating r inner join
           rateelement r1
           on r.elementid =' at line 3 SQL6.sql 2 1 `